# Can a station roam seamlessly between 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz radios?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am planning to set up multiple Wireless Access Points around my house. Most of my devices are 2.4Ghz only, while some are capable of 5Ghz. My WAPs are a mix of the 2 bands also. I used to set them up broadcast the same SSID on multiple 2.4Ghz channels, and they worked well. Now the 5Ghz band complicates the setup.

If I set up multiple 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz WAPs, which broadcast the same SSID, can a station roam seamlessly between them? And regardless of yes or no, what would happen if I set up a WAP which has both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz radios to broadcast the same SSID on both radios silmutaneously -- what would the station pick when it enters the hotspot?

Comment: I don't think that seamless roaming is achievable here.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by _"...set up multiple 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz WAPs..."_ - it sounds like what you ultimately want are wireless repeaters, which would be the recommended way to go here, else you're going to be connecting to different subnets and routing gets more complicated than it needs to be. To set up a wireless router as a repeater, it requires a specific set of steps you should be able to find either via the OEM's support page (if not running opensource firmware), or via google.

Comment: @JW0914: Usually 'Access point' means a bridge-type device, which does not create a different subnet. OP did not mention they want to use a "wireless router" – many companies sell actual dedicated access points (e.g. UniFi) which don't have _any_ routing features at all and are specifically made for seamless roaming.

Comment: @JW0914 Nope, I hate all kind of wireless connection unless it is impossible to use wire. In fact, I have done a lot of work to run (and hide) wires from the main router to all Access Points (AP) across several houses -- most of them are cheap router/switch/AP combo with router function and DHCP disabled to work as a standalone AP. I know what I am doing, but I lack the basic knowledge about how Wi-Fi works, so I asked to make sure they shall work as intended. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I set up multiple 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz WAPs, which broadcast the same SSID, can a station roam seamlessly between them?

Yes, it should be as seamless as roaming between two 2.4GHz APs. A station can always just disassociate from one AP and associate with another, whenever it wants; this does not revoke its DHCP lease or forcibly kill connections.

(Exactly *how* seamless depends on AP configuration, e.g. whether they and clients support 802.11r etc. But it shouldn't be different from roaming in the same band.)

> what would happen if I set up a WAP which has both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz radios to broadcast the same SSID on both radios silmutaneously -- what would the station pick when it enters the hotspot?

It varies; often stations pick 5 GHz first. For example, here's how Apple implements roaming – the 5 GHz network is preferred as long as its signal strength is above a certain minimum:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203068
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206207

Android prefers 5 GHz as well, but uses a 'scoring' system so other factors may influence this:

- https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-network-selection

Comment: As I understand your answer, the SSID is just some kind of text advertisement made by Access Points (in beacon packets). The stations get a list of all APs, and they assume that the same SSID represents the same underlying network, and will try to connect to the "best" AP as long as their radio hardware is capable of doing it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's basically how it works.

Comment: Is there any strict requirements for roaming to work, other than SSID and password? Can other parameters differ between APs such as: channel width, encryption method, 802.11 versions?

Comment: Some clients will refuse to roam to a 'weak encryption' AP, e.g. if you connect to a network using WPA2-AES on Windows it will not automatically roam to an open or WPA1-TKIP access point offering the same SSID. Differences in 'physical link' parameters are not important, since in the end a roaming client still fully disconnects from the old AP and connects normally to the new one. (Even protocols like FT/802.11r don't change this, they just make the process faster.)

Comment: After more than 2 years, now a new problem arises. WPA3 access points have been introduced into my network. I set them to operate in `sea-mixed` mode to allow both WPA3 devices and WPA2 devices to connect. The problem is most access points remain WPA2-only (`psk2+ccmp`). Do WPA3 devices roam between WPA3 and WPA2 access points?